# JW play a video inline on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, jwplayer

We do not want the video to go full screen when it plays, because then is inpossible to hide tollbar, iPhone native settings will override.

Maybe exist some Workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you become stuck inside the player with no way out. I've been there my friend!

You can use the JW Player iOS SDK (not free), or you can do what I did and implement video in your Ionic app using [Videogular](http://www.videogular.com/). It's a nice player and it worked well for me.